# Install Java to Android machine

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, termux

I recently put Android on my Windows laptop. I want to run Selenium-Webdriver for automation and development. I need Java for Selenium to run this on my Android machine.

This is my first time ever (obviously) putting Android on a laptop and was wondering how to put JDK on it.

I have tried researching this and have had no luck.

Note: I have Termux - so I was able to install everything from NodeJS, Protractor, Selenium, etc.

I tried installing GNURoot Debian as suggested and the application is launching with an error. I have researched the issue and no luck.
Also, the APK file that was in the Stack Overflow answer was invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install the JDK on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539308/is-it-possible-to-install-the-jdk-on-an-android-device)

Comment: I tried that and no luck for two reasons: 1) app is not working properly 2) even if terminal emulator worked, the path specified to copy to was invalid