# how can I install java runtime on Android device?

Tags: android, linux, java-8, command, adb

I need to install some packages and ***Linux programs on my android devices***. for example I want to use something similar ***YUM or get-apt*** command (*I know these are Linux Commands*) through windows powershell connected to my android device. but it does not recognize these commands. ***even ADB does not work***, e.g. ***adb update -y*** is unknown command. How can i do this, is it possible. if the android kernel is linux so I guess there must be a way. I checked this but didnt help me:

[Is it possible to install the JDK on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539308/is-it-possible-to-install-the-jdk-on-an-android-device)

Thanks

EDITED: I used the link below , thanks to my friend for good answer. this is the command i used :

pkg install wget && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MasterDevX/java/master/installjava && bash installjava

BUT when i run java command it says "Killed". No Idea!

Answer (score 3):

Try [**Termux**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en), a linux terminal emulator for android.A minimal base system is installed automatically - additional packages are available using the APT package manager. You can use following commands to install java8.

1. pkg install git
2. git clone https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-Java.git
3. cd Termux-Java
4. chmod +x installjava
5. bash installjava

When installed, run ***java -version*** to check, if it's correcty installed.
After that you can run java using ***Java*** command.

Comment: Thanks I will try it right now. but could you tell me if I am able to run most of the command which comes with YUM or apt-get ? thanks.

Comment: Yeah. you can.. termux is a complete linux environment.

Comment: Also i cheked it now yum update -y and apt-get update -y , both tells me not command found!

Comment: I think its happening due to an architecture mismatch. Check this out : https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1808

Comment: I think you also need `pkg install wget -y`

Answer (score 2):

$ apt update && apt upgrade
$ apt install openjdk-17

Comment: Do not just write some command, but also explain what the command does and why it it necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to install termux from their f droid link. Their playstore version is not updated. You can find the fdroid link from their github repository.

run the following command:

```
apt update
apt search openjdk
```

If you find a version of openjdk available, for example : `presently openjdk-17 is available`

install it using command:

```
apt install package-name
```

example:

```
apt install openjdk-17
```

follow the prompts and java will be installed in your termux.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install termux.
Then run following commands  :

`$ pkg update -y && pkg upgrade -y`


`$ termux-setup-storage`

And give the storage permission.
After that download these 2 files.

**JDK-9 :**   https://archive.org/download/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_x86_64/openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb

**JRE-9 :**    https://archive.org/download/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_x86_64/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb

Remember the filenames,  and the folder where you downloaded the files.

Go back to termux and run :

`$ cd /sdcard/<folder name>`

Replace foldername  with your download folder.

`$ mv file1 file2 $HOME`

Replace file1 and file2 with actual filenames.

**Alternative :**

If you don’t want to download and move files manually you can use this commands (not recommended) :

`$ pkg install wget -y`


`$ wget https://archive.org/download/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_x86_64/openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb`


`$ wget https://archive.org/download/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_x86_64/openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb`

It will download files within your termux home directory.

Finally run,

`$ apt-get install -y ./openjdk-9-jdk-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb`


`$ apt-get install -y ./openjdk-9-jre-headless_9.2017.8.20-1_arm.deb`

And You're done.
Try typing  `java` or `javac`.
If you don’t see an Error you're good to go.

[See Source](https://www.mrtechx.com/2020/07/how-to-install-java-in-termux.html?m=1)

Answer (score 1):

Install termux and run these commands

```
pkg update

pkg install openjdk-17

java --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Download java is possible
Check this github link

Termux java https://github.com/EagleComrade/Termux-java.git

It provides direct installtion of java from termux-source
Installtion from unwanted sources are not really trusted
So this tool is realy great
Do the following for install java without errors.

```
      pkg install git

     git clone https://github.com/EagleComrade/Termux-java.git

    cd Termux-java
 
    chmod +x install.sh

    ./install.sh
```

Java is installed .......

Answer (score 0):

search 'java runtime environment' at google play, will find one apk, then you can install it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Install ubuntu on termux from anlinux... Then use

```
$ apt install default-jdk
```

Job done!